# What are best practices for using Ansible Vault on public CI's and Source Control Repositories like BitBucket?

Tags: ansible-vault, bitbucket

**Introduction**

On a private CI's and Source Control Repositories like Gitlab-ce it is possible to copy an ~/.vault_pass.txt to the server and let it use by the CI to decrypt files using Ansible.

**Problem**

On public CI's and Source Control Repositories like Bitbucket it is not possible to copy a ~/.vault_pass.txt to the CI server it self.

**Discussion**

In Bitbucket it is possible to define encrypted variables, but when [this](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/constants.py) file is checked the only VAULT related variables are:

- `ANSIBLE_ASK_VAULT_PASS`
- `ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE`

These variables are not an option to solve the issue as when the `ANSIBLE_ASK_VAULT_PASS` is set `ansible-vault` still prompts:

```
user@host $
Vault password:
```

When the same password is entered it can open the encrypted file, but the aim is to open the file without needing a file or entering a password in a prompt.

Another attempt to solve the issue was running `export ANSIBLE_ASK_VAULT_PASS=<ansible-vault-password>`, but the interactive mode persists.

Another option is `export ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=~/.vault_pass.txt`, but then this file needs to be pushed to the repository, but source Control repositories should not contain passwords.

Comment: Hi @030, could you clarify what you mean by CI?  To me this means **Continuous Integration**, however both GitLab and BitBucket are also Source Control Repositories - the question would be clearer if CI was expanded out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`--vault-password-file` can instead point to an executable script that writes to stdout. This little-known feature should solve your problem.

First, write a simple, executable script that prints a system environment variable, and check that into your source control. Then, use Bitbucket's encrypted variable feature to set that environment variable to your ansible-vault secret. Finally, execute like so:

`ansible-playbook site.yml --vault-password-file ./mypass.sh`.

References:

1. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html#running-a-playbook-with-vault
2. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-devel/1vFc3y6Ogto

Comment: And then the mypass.sh will contain `echo $VAR` for example and this var will be set in the BitBucket UI?

Comment: Yup! Alternatively, here's a Python example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/access-environment-variables-from-python

Comment: `([Errno 8] Exec format error). If this is not a script, remove the executable bit from the file.`

Answer (score 3):

Using

```
ansible-playbook site.yml --vault-password-file ./mypass.sh
```

resulted in:

```
ERROR! Problem running vault password script / p a t h / t o
/ e c h o _ v a u l t _ p a s s . s h ([Errno 8] Exec format error). If this is 
not a script, remove the executable bit from the file.
```

Based on [this post](http://www.kdelemme.com/2016/07/06/use-ansible-to-deploy-with-circleci/) the following was defined in bitbucket-pipelines:

```
image: docker:latest

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - echo $ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD > .vault_password.txt
          - ansible-playbook -i ansible/inventory ansible/site.yml --vault-password-file .vault_password.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

You could have a test set up that does not run production, and load different files for those.

Create a host_vars/localhost/vault that only works for the local test installation.

That way you could use a open vault password that works only for that local host vault.